vision pro file copy Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=102 "(null)

Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=102 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x300019dd0 {Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Generation not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=Generation not found}}}

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FilePickerView>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: .import) // 设置为.import以允许用户选择文件
        documentPicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        documentPicker.title = "4xVR"
        return documentPicker
    }
  
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FilePickerView>) {
    }
 
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
 
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        var parent: FilePickerView
 
        init(parent: FilePickerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
 
        func documentPicker( controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            
            if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.import{
                
                for url in urls {
                    /// 源文件名字
                    let  sourceName = url.lastPathComponent
                    /// 源文件路径
                    let soureUrlPath =  url.path
                    
                    let documentBaseUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
                    let targartUrl = documentBaseUrl!.appendingPathComponent(sourceName)
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: soureUrlPath, toPath: targartUrl.path) //FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URL.init(string: soureUrlPath)!, to:ulr!)
                        print("Success to copy file.")
                        
                    } catch  {
                        print("Failed to copy file.")
                    }
    //                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("FileShareNotice"), object: self, userInfo: nil)
                    //            }
                    
                }
            }
        }
           
        func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            // Handle cancellation if needed
            print(" copying file: Cancelled")
        }
    }


Could you please add English translations for the comments? Also an explanation of the problem, how to trigger it, and what you’d like to know. It doesn’t look to me like this is specific to visionOS; is it?
